# Gerund as a passive adjective

Tags: adjectives, nouns, gerunds

I have a question about using a gerund as an adjective for a noun. I think the right name is "Present-Participial Adjectives
". I want to refer to a "material" that is being "injected" just right now. So, if I say "injected material" it means that the material has already been injected. If I use "injecting material", it means that the material is the subject and it is injecting something else (completely nonsense). And if I use "being injected material", it seems off and not common to me as I searched it through the internet, and I could not find many examples of it.

I would be grateful if you send me your suggestions.

Best regards,
Masoud

Comment: Could you give some examples, in full sentences?

Comment: Is this material being injected a vaccine?

Comment: Yes. For example:
When the viscosity rises, it is more difficult for the motor to push the "injecting material" out to the site of interest.

Comment: There's no law that says you can't switch to another form, like the *flow*. When the viscosity rises, it is more difficult for the motor to push the flow out.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that **the being injected material* doesn't make sense, but ***the material being injected*** is perfectly fine.

This is a type of ***[reduced relative clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107)*** - reduced to a present participle phrase. The only particular element is that the verb ***inject*** is used in the passive, which is why the auxiliary ***be*** takes the *-ing* form.

Answer (score 0):

Take 200ml of **the material to be injected**